# The add_action('register_form') isn't effecting my registration form

Tags: plugins, user-registration

This is my first plugin and I've read through many tutorials from wordpress and others but I'm stuck. Here is my code.

```
<?php 
/*
  Plugin Name: lola-registration
  Description: Adds fields to registration page
  Version: 1.0
  Author: Myname
 */

add_action( 'register_form', 'lola_register_form' );

function lola_register_form() {

?>
    <p>
        <label for="firstname"><?php _e('First Name') ?><br />
        <input type="firstname" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['firstname']); ?>" size="25" tabindex="20" />
    </label>
</p>
```

I know I'm close because if I change 'register_form' to 'login_form' it will add the first name field to the login form. I feel like it's going to be something simple in the theme settings or some configuration file I just haven't been able to get it. Any ideas?

Comment: You should include, what you are hoping to accomplish, and what you see now.

Comment: I literally just figured it out. As I have a multisite I needed to use 'signup_extra_fields' rather than 'register_form'. I will keep your posting guidelines in mind for the next time I have a questions though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Wordpress 3.0.0, the action to call is "signup_extra_fields" instead of "register_form", so you should use:

```
add_action( 'signup_extra_fields', 'extended_register_form' );
```